# req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result always returns null when accessed from browser (but not in Azure Portal)

Tags: azure-functions, azureportal, httpresponsemessage

Below contains my full code (Azure Function App on Azure Portal). Take extra attention on these two lines.

`var jsonContent = req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
 log.LogInformation("jsonContent" + jsonContent);`

When I test the function using the **request body** under panel on the right, the `jsonContent` is printed out in the Logs as it should. However, using the **function url** in a browser, and append it with `&name=azure`, the `jsonContent` is null as shown in the Logs.

```cs
//full code
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;

using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log)
{
    // these two lines are problematic???
    var jsonContent = req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    log.LogInformation("jsonContent" + jsonContent);

    // you can ignore the following lines (not related to question)
    string jsonToReturn = "Hello World";

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {
        Content = new StringContent(jsonToReturn, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    };
}
```

I tried changing the line to this but it didn't work either.

`var jsonContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`

The error is something like

`'string' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Anyway, I know a workaround that is to use `HttpRequest` instead of `HttpRequestMessage` to generate `jsonContent`, but I'm just curious why the case doesn't work.

Can anyone spot my mistake? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you append function url in browser with `&name=azure`, it **sets the name=azure as http request header**. So, if you want to send http request with request body, you could use **postman** to trigger the Azure Function.

Here is my test:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Indeed, appending as query is very different from using request body! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Appending as query is different from using request body. You can call the function along with request body in Python like this (just an example):

```py
reqBody = {
        'customerid' : customerid,
        'imgdata' : imgdata
    }
headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
url = "https://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/HTTPTrigger.............."
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers,
                             data=json.dumps(reqBody))
print(response.json())
```